# Chef - ohai unable to find README file

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, chef-solo, devops

Just did a `chef-solo` run. I have my cookbook defined in `~/chef-repo/cookbooks/my-cookbook`, and all the dependencies were installed by `berkshelf` in `~/.berkshelf/cookbooks`

```
chef-solo -c solo.rb -j params.json
```

I keep running into an error from `ohai`. I gather that `ohai` is a library that provides environment configurations, and my `nginx-2.7.6` cookbook relies on `ohai` (`2.0.1`).

```
[2015-06-25T15:19:08-04:00] DEBUG: RuntimeError: remote_directory[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins for cookbook ohai] (ohai::default line 33) had an error: RuntimeError: cookbook_file[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/README] (dynamically defined) had an error: RuntimeError: File files/default/plugins/README does not exist for cookbook ohai
```

I've looked into `/etc/chef/ohai` and it's right that there's no `README` there (that folder is empty, in fact). Not sure what it's looking for or how to solve this error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to ohai's supermarket readme it must be the first item on your runlist
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ohai#readme

Give that a shot and see if it works.